# How can you control implicit insert/remove animations of a SwiftUI List View?

Tags: ios, macos, animation, swiftui, swiftui-list

Imagine a simple list like this:

```swift
List {
    if expanded {
        Text("abc")
        Text("abc2")
        Text("abc3")
    }
    Text("abc4")
    Text("abc5")
}
```

Now if I toggle the expanded boolean using a withAnimation: block, I see an insert/remove animation of the first three items. But I couldn't find any way to control the speed or style of that animation? I tried using `.animation()` and/or `.transition()` modifiers in multiple ways, but no luck.

Comment: No way for now - only default one. You can use ScrollView + LazyVStack to make custom behavior.